# iptables: Route all traffic from IP:PORT to interface

Tags: iptables

I want to route all tcp outgoing traffic from 192.168.2.99:16881 to an interface: tun1
I also want to have all tcp incoming traffic from tun1 on $PORT to be redirected to 192.168.2.99:16881.

What I have at the moment is this script:

```
#1 Get the PORT
PORT=`./port_forwarding.sh`

#2 Accept incoming traffinc on $PORT 
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport $PORT -j ACCEPT 

#3 Route all TCP incoming trafinc on $PORT to 192.168.2.99:16881
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j DNAT -p tcp --dport $PORT --to-destination 192.168.2.99:16881

#4 Route all TCP outgoing traffic from 192.168.2.99 to tun1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface tun1 -j MASQUERADE -s 192.168.2.99
```

Thoses rules doesn't seems to work, what should I change?
2 & 3: Should I specify the interface tun1?
4: How can I specify the source port?